# Compare results from Julia MLJ models

Tags: machine-learning, julia

I'd like to train 3 models in [MLJ.jl](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/MLJ.jl): ARDRegressor, AdaBoostRegressor, BaggingRegressor

Currently, I train them 1 at a time for example:

```
using Pkg; Pkg.activate("."); Pkg.instantiate();
using RDatasets, MLJ, Statistics, PrettyPrinting, GLM   
X, y =  @load_boston; train, test = 1:406, 407:506 

@load ARDRegressor
reg = ARDRegressor
m = machine(reg(), X, y);
fit!(m, rows=train);
ŷ = predict(m, rows=test)
os_ARDRegressor = rms(ŷ , y[test])
```

I'd like to train them w/ a loop such as:

```
modlist = [ARDRegressor; AdaBoostRegressor; BaggingRegressor]  
score = []

for (i, mod) in enumerate(modlist)
@load mod;
reg = mod;
m = machine(reg(), X, y);
fit!(m, rows=train);
ŷ = predict(m, rows=test)
push!( score,  (i, mod, rms(ŷ , y[test]))  )
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues in running your last code block.

- The loop `for jj in eachindex(Models)` iterates over the indices of the `Models` array, so `jj` takes the values 1, 2, 3. Rather loop over the `Models` array directly.
- `@load ARDRegressor` is a macro invocation; this means `@load jj` will translate to `@load("jj")`, so doesn't use `jj` like the variable you intended.
- The value of `os_jj` will be overwritten on every iteration of the loop. You rather want to keep the score in an array at that index: `os[jj] = ...`
- MLJ requires you to import the packages that contain the models before loading them. Remind yourself that `using ScikitLearn` requires the sklearn python package to be installed in your current environment.

Consider the following working code example:

```
using MLJ, RDatasets
X, y =  @load_boston; train, test = 1:406, 407:506 
models = [@load ARDRegressor; @load AdaBoostRegressor; @load BaggingRegressor]
score = Array{Float64}(undef, 3)
for (i, model) in enumerate(models)
    m = machine(model, X, y)
    fit!(m, rows=train);
    ŷ = predict(m, rows=test)
    score[i] = rms(ŷ, y[test])
end
@show score
```

Side note: the use of `using Pkg; Pkg.activate(".")` is unnecessary when running julia using this command: `julia --project`. But this comes down to personal preference

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but with my own code. How should one do it when each machine takes a different number of parameters?  For instance, I have kernel regression a model that takes a sampling mask with the positions of the samples. Here's the question I asked about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473668/iterating-over-different-functions-with-different-number-of-parameters-in-julia?noredirect=1#comment105126050_59473668 I'd appreciate any help